# Warning: @import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on angular app and while run the app it's not showing any errors but I'm getting this kind of warning's in many css files.

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Warning

 (114:1) @import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)
```

What I have imported on 114 line is this.

```
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
```

Where ever I have imported like this in all that css showing this kind of warnings.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: please put complete component code along with the question so we can check actual problem.

Comment: I'm just importing CSS for Font Awesome 3.2.1.

Comment: put import line top of the file and move all the css import to the styles array in the angular.json file.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the help.@SainPradeep

Comment: @SainPradeep good solution. But, isn't this make css project wise ? What if you would like to import some css component wise ?

Answer (score 23):

I want to explain it through two screenshots that why it is giving warning.
Because you are not using **@import** ....line at first line.
**See this screenshot it is giving warning.**
[image]

**see below screenshot this is the solution:**

**Warning has gone because I have used @import ... line at first line in styles.css file.**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your *css loader plugin* attempts to follow the `@import` where **its not at the top** of (**first lines** of) the css file. `@import` statements must precede all other statements (besides `@charset`).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help
It solved it for me by replacing `@import "@angular/material/_theming.scss";` with `@use "~@angular/material" as mat;`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67850942/16298287