# SCSS. Angular Material Issue during Angular migration from version 11 to 12

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I have a problem in my .scss files after migration of Angular & Angular Material from 11 to 12 version

[image]

Code block that causes such error is next:

[image]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. @use '~@angular/material' as mat;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652012/sasserror-cant-find-stylesheet-to-import-use-angular-material-as-mat)

Comment: I saw this answer and tried to remove `~` sign from imports and it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

node-sass is deprecated

To solve the problem I ran: `npm uninstall node-sass` and next `npm i sass --save-dev`. Solved